# ::selection does not work on text which has ::first-letter

Tags: css, google-chrome

`::selection` does not work on text which has `::first-letter`. This is code:

```css
p::first-letter {
  font-size: 130%;
}

::selection {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<p>hello</p>
```

<kbd>[Live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Hongbo_Miao/zf4m30c9/18/)</kbd>

When you select, it does not apply the color to **h**

[image]

I tried to add `!important`, but still does not work.

```
::selection {
  background: red !important;
  color: white !important;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remember coming across this a long time ago..

It's a known bug in chrome which still seems to be an issue!

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=17528

Comment: I think you are correct! I just found out `::-moz-selection` actually can apply color to the text in Firefox.

Comment: Yeah, it's kind of annoying, but firefox does work correctly with the -moz prefix

Comment: It also happens to Safari

Comment: Yep, chrome and safari use the webkit engine so the issue would be present there as well